# Firestore cost effective way of keeping only the most recent documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a subcollection with logs, but only want to keep the X most recent logs for storage concerns. I'm trying to figure out the most cost-effective way of keeping that log collection small. (Logs all have timestamps)

**UPDATE**

Seems the solution is to *run a maintenance job server side once every X days to delete extra logs.*

But that leads to my next question. **Is there a way to query the opposite of a limit?** For example:

I have 105 logs, I need to keep the 100 first. Can I query all except 100 first? Or is the only way to bite the bullet and do these 105 reads and then 5 deletes.

Comment: It doesn't matter how large your collection is when querying for results in firestore :)

Comment: But the query is reads, right? So query 100 docs = 100 reads (then 100 deletes if you want to delete)

Comment: Thats true. But what does it matter if you store it in subcollections yes or no? In the end, you always query an X amount of documents. Those X amount is equal to: store everything in 1 big collection (which doesn't matter), or everything in subcollections.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just keep them? You can always run an external weekly/monthly cron job that calls a https trigger to batch delete logs older than a certain date.

date, and currentDate being a unixTimeStamp.

When you retrieve documents you can use `where(date, "<=", currentDate).limit(x)`

Comment: I'm thinking of indeed keeping them and then running a cron job once in a while. But the thing is, I don't want to delete older than X, I want to keep Y most recent. Not sure the best way to do this. I'm thinking: read all logs in time sorted order, get timestamp of 10th one, then re-query where time is older than timestamp. Anyway to do it in only one query? At that point, I guess I'm reading all the logs. Might as well just get all of them, delete everyone older than the 10th one.

Answer (score 2):

Daily or weekly job sounds about right.

OrderBy and limit should work for the query.

```
it("should order and limit", () => {
    var logRef = db.collection("log");
    // [START order_and_limit]
    logRef.orderBy("date").limit(10)
    // [END order_and_limit]
 });
```

[Firebase Query Snippets](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/8944ede35756f6d91488124b7fa71e8d8487d2e2/firestore/test.firestore.js#L797-L797)